# Plotting frequencies in Seaborn

Tags: jupyter, seaborn

I'm looking at an SNL dataset and I want to use seaborn to take a look at a couple different things.

I'm using this to learn more about visualizations in jupyter (aka I'm a beginner).

The data set looks like this:
[image]

aid: actor
capacity: what their role was
charid: unique character id
impid: unique impersonation id
role: name of role they played
tid: sketch id
voice: were they just a voiceover?
epid: episode id
sid: season id

Some questions:
Who are the top 20 actors who appeared on SNL?
The characters used most frequently?
The impressions most frequently?
Which characters were played by multiple actors?

I tried this but it's so many people, I want to limit it to maybe 20 people. Or if you have suggestions of other visualizations to try I'm all ears.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5)) 
sns.countplot(y="aid", data=appearances);
```

Some example plots of how to answer some of these questions would be amazing!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite broad but in general, for each series, you can do this:

Get the count for each unique element of a specific column and only take the 20 elements with the highest count:

```
top20aid=appearances.groupby(['aid'],sort=False)['aid'].count().sort_values().tail(20)
    bot20aid=appearances.groupby(['aid'],sort=False)['aid'].count().sort_values().head(20)
```

NB: `sort_values`, by default, sort in ascending order. Hence to find the values with the highest count we use `tail()`. You can sort in descending order by using the following `.sort_values(ascending=False)`. In this case you would select the elements with the highest count using `.head()`. e.g.

```
top20aid=appearances.groupby(['aid'],sort=False)['aid'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20)
bot20aid=appearances.groupby(['aid'],sort=False)['aid'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).tail(20)
```

Then simply plot the results in a `barplot`

```
sns.barplot(top20aid.values,top20aid.index)
```